# Dynamically add a constructor

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to dynamically add a constructor to a Class *without* altering the original Class itself?

I'm using a library where I instantiate objects like so:

```
var path = new Path()
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
// obviously won't work but you get the point
Path.prototype.constructor = function() {
  console.log(this, 'was created')
}

var path = new Path()
```

I can obviously use a Factory to create my objects and in that Factory I can add a custom function and trigger it. That won't work since the library I'm using won't be using that factory internally.

Comment: might help you https://gist.github.com/parwat08/94071d1ba6df156d5e3b2436b250c13b

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your context, could you extend the class?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan No. If I extend the Class, the library internals won't be using my extended Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but the variable `Path` needs to be non-`const` in order for it to work. This approach will require you to still call the original `constructor`:

```
Path = class extends Path {
  constructor () {
    super()
    console.log(this, 'was created')
  }
}
```

```js
class Path {
  constructor () {
    console.log('old constructor')
  }
  
  foo () {
    console.log('bar')
  }
}

Path = class extends Path {
  constructor () {
    super()
    console.log(this, 'was created')
  }
}

let path = new Path()
path.foo()
```

You can also replace `Path` with a new class identical to the original except for the `constructor`:

```
Path = (Path => {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf(
    Object.setOwnPropertyDescriptors(function () {
      console.log(this, 'was created')
    }, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Path)),
    Object.getPrototypeOf(Path)
  )
})(Path)
```

```js
class Path {
  constructor () {
    console.log('old constructor')
  }

  foo () {
    console.log('bar')
  }
}

Path = (Path => {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf(
    Object.defineProperties(function () {
      console.log(this, 'was created')
    }, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Path)),
    Object.getPrototypeOf(Path)
  )
})(Path)

let path = new Path()
path.foo()
```